# Set the data property value when the promise has resolved

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

In my app , I need to connect to the mysql backend using Sequelize . Following is the code

```
export default {
        data () {
            return {
                username:''
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            this.dbConnect()
        },
        methods: {
            dbConnect : function () {
                console.log("Test connecting to the database");
                let connection = new Sequelize('mydatabase','root','12345' , {
                  host: '127.0.0.1',
                  dialect: 'mysql',
                  logging: console.log.bind(console)
                });

                var userGroup = connection.define('roles',{
                    name:Sequelize.STRING
                },{ freezeTableName: true, timestamps : false})

                userGroup.findById(1).then(function(group) {
                    this.username =  group.get('name');
                    console.info('current username is :' + this.username);
                })

            }
        }
    }
```

Everything is working fine, except that by the time
`this.username = group.get('name)`  gets resolved my UI has already rendered. Is there a way I can update my data property so that its updated properly in my view ?

Comment: is `this.username =  group.get('name');` adding to the vue instance? you are doing that modification in the callback, so can you check if `this` is the vue instance or `window`?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal : I am sorry I did not understand your question. username is a data property so it should be added to the Vue instance, no?  Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect. thanks

Comment: I mean, after this`console.info('current username is :' + this.username);` try to console `console.info(this);` do you see vue instance or window object?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal : You are correct. this was an instance of Sequelize . It now works for me.. Can you please post this as an answer and I will mark it as so .. thanks once again sir !

Comment: could you please add the javascript tag, my answer hurts my eyes without the syntax highlighting x_x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points

```
dbConnect : function () {
                console.log("Test connecting to the database");
                let connection = new Sequelize('mydatabase','root','12345' , {
                  host: '127.0.0.1',
                  dialect: 'mysql',
                  logging: console.log.bind(console)
                });

                var userGroup = connection.define('roles',{
                    name:Sequelize.STRING
                },{ freezeTableName: true, timestamps : false})

                userGroup.findById(1).then(function(group) {
                    this.username =  group.get('name'); // [1]
                    console.info('current username is :' + this.username);
                })

            }
```

at [1] you are, setting to the window object a property called `username`.

you need to change your function to something like:

```
userGroup.findById(1).then((group) => {
    this.username =  group.get('name');
    console.info('current username is :' + this.username);
})
```

or you can set a variable like

```
let self = this
userGroup.findById(1).then(function(group) {
    self.username =  group.get('name');
    console.info('current username is :' + self.username);
})
```

The other point I'd like to make, please use vuex actions for your async calls.

Answer (score 1):

[Vue Lifecycle Hooks Diagram](https://vuejs.org/images/lifecycle.png)

The `mounted` lifecycle hook refers to when the `Vue` instance has been created and the respective `el` component has been replaced with `vm.$el`.

If the resolution of the promise is taking too long to be complete before the visual rendering of the instance, try setting it back to an event on the `created` hook. That's where I usually do a lot of preprocessing and gathering of data for Vue instances with external services and it always works out well.

So instead of...

```
mounted() {
    this.dbConnect()
}
```

...do it in...

```
created() {
    this.dbConnect()
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can use conditional rendering of your Vue instance to trigger full rendering once the connection is made and the promise is complete.

Just for your outer element in the HTML, add..

```
<div v-if="!isProcessing">
    <!-- contents -->
</div>
```

and a slight addition to your JS:

```
export default {
        data () {
            return {
                username:'',
                isProcessing: true
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            this.dbConnect()
        },
        methods: {
            dbConnect : function () {
                console.log("Test connecting to the database");
                let connection = new Sequelize('mydatabase','root','12345' , {
                  host: '127.0.0.1',
                  dialect: 'mysql',
                  logging: console.log.bind(console)
                });

                var userGroup = connection.define('roles',{
                    name:Sequelize.STRING
                },{ freezeTableName: true, timestamps : false})

                userGroup.findById(1).then((group) => {
                    this.username =  group.get('name');
                    this.isProcessing = false;
                    console.info('current username is :' + this.username);
                })

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I did what you suggested but it ain't working .. I am sorry. Same issue

Comment: then I'd suggest using conditional rendering of the instance based on a `processing` (or something like that) variable that is `true` and set to `false on load. I'll update answer, hold on...